# PHP Code coverage command giving Target class router does not exist error

Tags: laravel, phpunit, code-coverage

Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format. I am running below command

```
sudo ./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-clover ./report.xml
```

which is giving below  error:

```
Target class [router] does not exist
```

All testcases are passed

getting this

```
Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... <<<<<<< HEAD
```

with error

Comment: Application not bootstrapped, this error says

Comment: As @Maksim mentioned, you should have a `phpunit.xml` and inside it you should have a property called `bootstrap`, do you have it? Share your `phpunit.xml` WITHOUT secrets or keys, please.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes, I have this line bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" in phpunit.xml

Comment: @Maksim Yes, I have this line bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" in phpunit.xml

Comment: @matiaslauriti I am using laravel lucid

Comment: @BhumiShah were you able to get this resolved? I get this exact same error when trying to generate coverage report. Same bootstrap line in phpunit.xml too.